# Admob show live ads but not after publishing

Tags: android, admob, ads

I already published my app and I was successfully able to show test ads and live ads. But after publishing my app ads doesnt show at all. I tried creating new app in admob and linked it to the app but still cant see ads.

To be more specific, by using the apk file that I uploaded to the store I can see ads, but if I download it from the store I cant see ads.

My app is not designed for families.

Please help me.